# Using custom font in android LatinIME keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I'm developing an Android Keyboard by modifying the LatinIME keyboard to write in languages that doesn't come with android originally. So, I'm trying to use a font other than the default android font in `EditText` fields when writing with that keyboard.

Note that I DON'T want the font of the Keys to be changed, I want the font of the Entered text to be changed according to my font.

Now while entering text in an EditText field, if I can get the reference of that EditText field, the task is as easy as:

```
Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/myFont.ttf");
referenceToEditText.setTypeface(myTypeface);
```

But the problem is how can I get the reference to the EditText field(the field where I'm entering text) ?

any ideas?

Comment: Hi, have you find out a solution ? I got the same problem, to do so, I have to root the android, do a CHMOD 777 on /system/fonts ([link]http://karuppuswamy.com/wordpress/2009/04/25/mounting-system-partition-in-read-write-mode-in-android/) and then overwrite font to use my own.

Answer (score 0):

In the onCreate function of your activity, get the edittext (using the id you set in the XML layout file), and then call setTypeFace:

```
EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
myEditText.setTypeface(Constant.APP_FONT);
```

Comment: I'm not suppossed to set EditText id in layout file, infact I'm not suppossed to have specific layout file. I'm developing a keyboard buddy

Comment: Ok I think I got it. You want to force an EditText font from the keyboard. I hope it's not that..

Comment: there is no 'my edittext', when I start to write an email body, the text field is of that email apps

Answer (score 0):

Are u talking about getting the input of the Edittextfield from your keyboard??
check this:

```
InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();

        CharSequence currentText = ic.getExtractedText(new ExtractedTextRequest(), 0).text;

        //Toast.makeText(this, currentText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```